# wireless ad hoc application c#

Tags: c#, adhoc

i try the write c# application that
for now will send some string between 
2 computer by ad-hoc network

i search  for some example or article,
but no found.

can some one can help me on that

tnx..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sending data between two computers on a wireless ad-hoc network should no different to sending data between two computers on a wired lan. You should be able to use the machines hostname or IP address and connect in the same way you would if it was not a wireless ad-hoc network.

Comment: Hi agine
sorry but i don't Understan..
how one or too cumputer can get ip?

and how can i set the computers to be kind of server?

thanks

Comment: Assuming you have already configured the ad hoc connection, open a socket on each of the computers, and send your string through this socket. Or any way you prefer. The connection being adhoc or regular WLAN, the code would be the same.

Comment: this is the problem i dont know how to "configured the ad hoc connection"

this is the help i need how to do it..

or were i can read about it
or see some example.

thanks agine.